# CSS issue with using display:inline-block

Tags: html, css

I have set up 4 divs all of width: 120px placed inside of a wrapper of 240px wide.

JSFiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/s7dxxro0/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">  
  <div class="primary-content-block" id="about">
  </div>
  <div class="primary-content-block" id="gallery">
  </div>
  <div class="primary-content-block" id="contact">
  </div>
  <div class="primary-content-block" id="news">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
margin:0 auto;
width: 240px;
}

.primary-content-block {
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
width: 120px;
height: 120px;
}

#about {
background: radial-gradient(#5cc4ba, #00aa99);
}

#gallery {
background: radial-gradient(#5cc4ba, #00aa99);
}

#contact {
background: radial-gradient(#5cc4ba, #00aa99);
}

#news {
background: radial-gradient(#5cc4ba, #00aa99);
}
```

However the elements to not display next to each other due to a slight margin being applied to my 4 blocks.

Where does this what seems to be a margin come from? How do I remove it?

This works when I use float:left in place of display:inline-block but I would prefer not to use floats for many reasons

Comment: add float:left; and increase the width of the container if it's not wide enough

Comment: Your code is working check here `http://jsfiddle.net/s7dxxro0/4/`

Comment: You could try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/s7dxxro0/3/), as the line breaks add space between your boxes.

Comment: The problem is the [white space between the divs](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/). This has been asked quite some times before.

Comment: That slight margin is caused by the space generated by the linebreaks. You can rather write the divs next to each other.

Same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements

Comment: @dcc Don't add it. Either use `float: left` *or* use `display: inline-block`. Now you have two solutions for the same issue (displaying them side by side). Also note that `float: left` will introduce other problems, especially if the blocks have a slightly different height. So no, while it may seem so at first, `float: left` is not the proper solution to this problem.

Comment: Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/s7dxxro0/9/)

Comment: Once again, I recommend reading http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: Agreed GolezTrol I do not want to use float:left due to the many issues is causes such as having no height value unless explicitly given

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because there are spaces between your inline blocks. The elements are separated by whitespace (new lines also count for this unfortunately), so the browser puts a space in between them as if they were words.

There's several ways to battle this.

Put the html tags side to side:

```
<div class="primary-content-block" id="about">
</div><div class="primary-content-block" id="gallery">
</div><div class="primary-content-block" id="contact">
```

Use a negative margin on the divs:

```
.primary-content-block {
    margin-right: -4px;
}
```

Set the font size to 0:

```
#wrapper {
    font-size: 0;
}
#wrapper > div {
    font-size: 12px /* or whatever it was before */
}
```

Or in case of `<p>` elements (not divs, unfortunately) just leave out the closing tag:

```
<p class="primary-content-block" id="about">
<p class="primary-content-block" id="gallery">
```

Source: [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Comment: I think negative margin is a bad solution, since you cannot know that the space is exactly 4px. The other solutions are good, and all of them will work.

Comment: @GolezTrol - you generally know in context what negative margin you do need. It's not always 4px, but it's a rare case that a correct negative margin in either px or em can't be chosen.

Comment: I agree Golez, it's not a perfect solution but I wanted to be complete. I don't like the font-size method either because it breaks `em` inheritance.

Comment: @isogram You might want to look into `rem` for that.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused by linebreaks between my divs

The fix would be:

```
<div id="wrapper">  
  <div class="primary-content-block" id="about"></div><div class="primary-content-block" id="gallery"></div><div class="primary-content-block" id="contact"></div><div class="primary-content-block" id="news"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simple add float: left the div

```
.primary-content-block {
    /* display:inline-block; */
    vertical-align:top;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    float: left;
}
```

like this http://jsfiddle.net/s7dxxro0/10/

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a "bug" (I don't think). It's just the way setting elements on a line works.The spaces between these blocks are just like spaces between words.
You can scoot the elements back into place with negative 4px of margin (may need to be adjusted based on font size of parent)

```
.primary-content-block {
   display:inline-block;
   vertical-align:top;
   width: 120px;
   height: 120px;
}
```